# Wifi driver install authorization

Tags: wireless

Bought a Netis wireless adapter. It comes with quick install directions that only covers WINDOWS although the driver CD has a Linux driver. Tried to install the driver (which was zipped) and was told that I didn't have sufficient permissions to extract the file. I am the only user and the administrator for the computer. How do I get to the Ubuntu 12.04 permission screen to put in my password and gain authorization?

Comment: Copy the file to desktop/ Home directory.

Then try to extract.

Comment: It is very likely there is a newer Linux driver than that found on the CD. Is it a PCI device? Please run lspci -nn in a terminal and edit your question to add its details. If USB, then run lsusb.

Comment: Web-E,  I did that. I was trying to unzip(extract) the driver from the home page when I ran into the problem

Comment: chili555,  I could be wrong but I don't think that the existence of a newer driver should prevent me from extracting a file. I did check the Netis web site but there was no help there. And they apparently don't believe in responding to customer questions, at least not quickly. I asked for help for installing the driver last Friday and haven't heard from them.

Comment: have you tried running your unzipper program of choice with sudo rights and unzip your drivers using the gui?: enter `sudo file-roller` into the terminal (ctrl + alt + T)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Archive Manager, when invoked within the GUI, prevents extraction of archives that can be extracted in a terminal window using "sudo tar" followed by the appropriate tar options and filename. sudo allows you to supply your password (to 
authorize an operation) before it is done.